# Can't modify existing logic to parse titles from next pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python using requests module to get the `titles` of different items populated upon initiating a search in `duckduckgo.com`. My search keyword is ***cricket***. My script is parsing the `titles` from the first page flawlessly.

[Website address](https://duckduckgo.com/html/)

I'm facing trouble parsing the `titles` from next pages as the `two fields` of `params` are increasing weirdly, as in `'s': '0'` and `'dc': '-27'`. However, the rest of the fields are static.

To parse `titles` from the first page, I tried like below (working):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://duckduckgo.com/html/"

params = {
    'q': 'python',
    's': '0',
    'nextParams': '',
    'v': 'l',
    'o': 'json',
    'dc': '-27',
    'api': 'd.js',
    'kl': 'us-en'
}

resp = requests.post(URL,data=params,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
for title in soup.select(".result__body .result__a"):
    print(title.text)
```

That two fields of the params are increasing like below:

1st page:

```
's': '0'
'dc': '-27'
```

2nd page:

```
's': '30'
'dc': '27'
```

Third page:

```
's': '80'
'dc': '76'
```

Fourth page:

```
's': '130'
'dc': '126'
```

***How can I scrape titles from next pages as well?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params for the next page are held in the POST response each time

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://duckduckgo.com/html/"

params = {
    'q': 'python',
    's': '0',
    'nextParams': '',
    'v': 'l',
    'o': 'json',
    'dc': '0',
    'api': 'd.js',
    'kl': 'us-en'
}

with requests.Session() as s:  
    while True:
        resp = s.post(URL,data=params,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
        for title in soup.select(".result__body .result__a"):
            print(title.text)
        for i in soup.select('form:not(.header__form) [type=hidden]'):  #updated params based on response
            params[i['name']] = i['value']
        if not soup.select_one('[value=Next]'):
            break
```